# I Cannot Get Dropped Event to Work in WebStorm Angular Material Project

Tags: javascript, angular, webstorm

While I have been programming since 1991 (yes I am THAT old), this is my first dive into Angular and I am attempting to use WebStorm 2021.2.3 to create a frontend restful interface.  The end result, eventually, will be draggable images of desktop/server icons with a menu on each that enables additional actions along with lines representing connections between all of them.  All based on a JSON object passed back and forth between my working restful middleware and this Angular frontend.

Of course, I cannot even get the basics working - so there is that.

I currently have the following code:

```js
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {CdkDragExit} from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-device-component',
  templateUrl: './device-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./device-component.component.css']
})
export class DeviceComponentComponent {
  exited(event: CdkDragExit<string[]>) {
    console.log('Exited', event.item.data);
  }
}
```

As well as this for my component frontend

```html
<div class="example-box" cdkDrag (cdkDragExited)="exited($event)">
<mat-card class="example-card">
  <mat-card-header>

  </mat-card-header>
  <img mat-card-image src="https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/dakirby309/simply-styled/256/Desktop-Windows-icon.png" alt="Windows 10">
  <mat-card-content>
      Windows 10 Machine
      <br /> Location 192.168.1.1
  </mat-card-content>
  <mat-card-actions>

  </mat-card-actions>
</mat-card>
</div>
```

The main app.module.ts:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {MatNativeDateModule} from '@angular/material/core';
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';

import {AppComponent} from "./app.component";
import {DeviceComponentComponent} from "./device-component/device-component.component";
import {MatCardModule} from "@angular/material/card";
import { DragDropModule } from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';
import {MatDialogModule} from "@angular/material/dialog";


/* the AppModule class with the @NgModule decorator */
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DeviceComponentComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    DragDropModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And my crazy advanced main app

```html
<div class="content" role="main">
  <app-device-component></app-device-component>
</div>
```

When I launch this component using npm run start in the Terminal window, I can drag the card around all day long but I never get the console output.

Can somebody PLEASE help me out here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in the [official doc](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/api#CdkDrag) you need containers (using CdkDropList directive) in order to trigger the cdkDragExited event listener. For your case I would suggest to use the cdkDragMoved event listener.

Comment: I still cannot get the Event Log in WebStorm to work but your response led me to the browser console window and everything worked.  Thank you.